# On hover show another div inside container div

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I do something like: when cursor pass over container div another div inside that container has other properties, For example I have a container div that contain another div with a background picture with opacity 0.2. I want to make child div,when cursor pass over container, visible 100% with properties opacity:1;
How can I do that?

Here is an example but unfortunately it works only if I pass cursor over child div:

**http://jsfiddle.net/Vqmaw/2129/**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the `#maifis:hover` rule to `#container:hover #maifis`. That basically means that when the **#container** is hovered, apply the rules to its child **#maifis**.

Working demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vqmaw/2132/)

Comment: @mcmwhfy The issue with IE8 is that it doesn't support `opacity` -- not the `:hover` rule. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

In modern browsers, this will work:

```
#maifis {
    opacity:0.2;
}
#container:hover #maifis {
    opacity:1;
}
```

The second CSS line means that when `#container` is hovered over, an element named `#maifis` contained by it has an opacity of 1.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, this is not possible with pure css. Based on your information and the jsfiddle, use this JQuery JS

```
$(function() {
    $('#container').bind('mouseover', function(){
        $('#maifis').addClass('visible');
    })
    $('#container').bind('mouseout', function(){
        $('#maifis').removeClass('visible');
    })
});
```

and change the `#maifis:hover` simply to `.visible` in your css.

Answer (score 0):

This with JQuery:

```
$('#maifis').hover( function(){
    $(this).animate({'opacity':1}, 300);
}, function(){
    $(this).animate({'opacity':0.2}, 300);
}); //Hover on maifis div
```

or:

```
$('#container').hover( function(){
    $('#maifis').animate({'opacity':1}, 300);
}, function(){
    $('#maifis').animate({'opacity':0.2}, 300);
}); //Hover on container div
```

Comment: Nice as it is, I don't think he wanted the element to change opacity gradually.